# Batch to read filenames from a file, move them to another dir and list in a text file any that failed

Tags: file, batch-file, move

I have a directory of 15,000 images, but only use 1500. I used excel to creaet a list of commands to move each of the 1500 images used to a new folder.

The problem is that only 1200 images were copied, leaving 300 images that we need to create or find.

I am trying to do the following:

File1 has a list of filenames
File2 is to list the filenames that are not avilable

for each filename in file1, read and move the file to another folder. If there is an error (no image to move), write that image name in another file, so we have a list of the 300 images we need to find.

Thanks for any help. I have a little batch experience, but this is a bit over my head.

Comment: This is not a question but a task request, which is off-topic here! To make it on-topic, share your efforts and clearly describe where you are stuck. Please learn [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) here!

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (excel_file.txt) do if exist "%%a" (move "%%a" "destinationdirectoryname") else (echo %%a>>cantfindthisfile.txt)
```

Not that hard...

Comment: Thanks Magoo. I forgot about the redirect >> and was trying to open the file write the line and close the file at the end. Then tried using std output. Your approach is much better and easier.